How do i make a 1inch hole in a door for a doorknob if i dont have a hole saw?
Ive drilled out as much as i could with my drill but its not the right size to fit the doorknob latch. So i need suggestions on what to do please.

Welcome to Woodworking Stack Exchange. You don’t need a hole saw to make holes. There are various drill bits that could do the job, depending on what you already have and how crisp the edges of the hole need to be (will it be covered by the knob?). This answer gives an overview of drill bits and what is appropriate for what: https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/a/2256/10115

If you have already drilled a smaller size hole, it will be more difficult, but not impossible, to re-drill it bigger. You can clamp a block of wood on top of the existing hole, so that the drill bit is not affected by it, and drill again.

I think, in this particular situation, obtaining the tool made specifically for the job may be the best solution to the problem. Having a hole saw, or a spade bit, (of the proper size) will make this job easier by factors. Buying new isn't a huge investment (even if it's a one-use tool) but obtaining a used one or a "loaner" isn't out of the question.

Hi, it's been a week since you asked this, did you figure it out for yourself, have you found a solution elsewhere or will you be returning to your Question here?
